# how to pass variable from store to apollo query

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-apollo

I'm trying to pass a variable in store into an apollo query but I can't find the proper way to do it. the variable I'm trying to use is  `user.username` and if I do `{{ user.username }}` in the template section it prints but within the script section `user` outputs as a weird Json type thing.
so ideally I want my query to work something like so:

```
export default {
  setup() {
    ...

    const query = gql`
        query ($username: String) {
            ...
        }
    `;

    const variables = ref({
      username: /* user.username */,
    })

    const {result, loading, error} = useQuery(query, variables);

    return {
      user,
      result,
      loading
    }
  }
```

I tried using computed() or Json.stringify and about a dozen other random things but nothing is working. There isn't any issues with the query itself since if I use a string like `username: "username"` the query works fine.

Hope I did a decent job at explaining things. thanks in advance

---

edit:
weird JSON thing:
home.vue:

```
<template>
  {{ user }}
</template>

<script>
import {useStore} from "vuex";
import {auth} from "@/firebaseConfig";
import {computed} from "vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    const store = useStore()

    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      store.dispatch("fetchUser", user);
    });

    const user = computed(() => {
      return store.getters.user;
    });

   console.log(user)

    return {
      user
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

output (console.log)

```
Object { _setter: setter(), dep: undefined, __v_isRef: true, __v_isReadonly: true, _dirty: true, effect: {…}, _cacheable: true }
​
__v_isReadonly: true
​
__v_isRef: true
​
_cacheable: true
​
_dirty: false
​
_setter: function setter()
​
Object { _setter: setter(), dep: undefined, __v_isRef: true, __v_isReadonly: true, _dirty: true, effect: {…}, _cacheable: true }
​
__v_isReadonly: true
​
__v_isRef: true
​
_cacheable: true
​
_dirty: false
​
_setter: function setter()
​
_value: Proxy { <target>: {…}, <handler>: {…} }
​​
<target>: Object { loggedIn: true, data: {…} }
​​​
data: Object { Username: "dxbh0517", … }

Username: "dxbh0517"
​​​​
uid: "2JlznrpQk"
​​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​​
loggedIn: true
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
<handler>: Object { get: get2(target, key, receiver), set: set2(target, key, value, receiver), deleteProperty: deleteProperty(target, key), … }
​
dep: Set [ {…} ]
​
effect: Object { fn: user(), scheduler: effect(), active: true, … }
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
Challenge.vue:30:12

​
dep: Set [ {…} ]
​
effect: Object { fn: user(), scheduler: effect(), active: true, … }
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

output ({{ user }}):

```
{ "loggedIn": true, "data": { "Username": "username", "uid": "2JlznrpQk" } }
```

Comment: please post the code showing your attempts. also helpful to paste the "weird JSON type thing" so we know what you're talking about.  without that info the best I can do is point to the [vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components)

Comment: @yoduh thanks for the tip! so I added the  output, you can see the data is under "_value" but if I use ` user.value.data ` in the console log it just come out as null.

Comment: does `user.value.username` work?  the way these proxy objects in Vue 3 work is that they wrap the "real" object which is stored as the inner `.value` property.  so `user.value` should give you the `user` object you expect with all its properties like username and uid.  they get unwrapped automatically when used in the template which is why `.value` isn't needed there.

Comment: @yoduh that worked thank you! had to use `user.value.data.username`

Comment: @yoduh ok so I was wrong `user.value` does work but `user.value.data` turns up `null` like half of the time, without any changes to the code so am I suppose to not use store like this and if so is there an alternative?

Comment: if `user.username` displays ok in the template, it should be `user.value.username` in your script.  Same goes for any other property.  Is `data` another actual property on your user object?  I'm not sure what would cause something to work only half the time.  The syntax for your store getter as a computed property in your component looks correct to me

Comment: I just doubled checked its `user.data.username` in the template so that explains why its `user.value.data`. if there isn't anything obviously wrong with the syntax my guess would be its something hidden somewhere that is messing with everything. I'll probably start a new project file and try it there maybe it will solve it. thanks for the help anyways